# Absolute Encoder hexadecimal input

Tags: c++, arduino, sensors, msp432

Question: How do I receive input from a absolute encoder that makes it output in hexadecimal/grey code into a Arduino? do I use a `digitalRead` or `analogRead` command? I could not find example code/projects with a absolute encoder online.

Overall Objective: I want to use a absolute encoder as a knob for a project. The idea is that the encoder will output its position as a state to be used in a case statement. I.e:

case1: `analogRead(absEncdr == 00)`
arduino enters idle routine

case2: `analogRead(absEncdr == 11)`
arduino enters button routine

etc

details: Abs encoder type: 25LB22-G
encoder datasheet is [here](http://www.grayhill.com/assets/1/7/Mech_Encoder_25L.pdf).

I'm using the hexidecimal/ grey code 4-Bit  Binary  Code    Hexadecimal-16  Position encoder version

Basically, I'm not sure how to read in this abs encoder into my Arduino.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read that you will need four digital pins.  You can read the four pins and bit-shift those values into one byte that you can compare to the table in the data-sheet.

```
byte position = (digitalRead(pin8) << 3) | (digitalRead(pin4) << 2) | (digitalRead(pin2) << 1) | digitalRead(pin1);
```

Assuming that the pins are named as they are in that truth table in the datasheet.

We are using the OR operator | to put them together into the same byte.

Comment: Thank you! I know its not part of the original question, but to use the abs encoder, would I have to connect the pins to pull-up resistors? The encoder has a "Common" or ground pin - but does not digress on powering the encoder

Comment: Whoops never mind! Turns out "common" in the application actually mean common voltage. I connected the C pin to the 5V rail with a resistor. and it works!